# Last time Row was updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Whats the best trigger for recording the last time a row is updated or inserted using a date column?

I tried this, but it is not working:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trUpdate ON Tablename FOR INSERT, UPDATE 
AS

  IF @@nestlevel = 0
  BEGIN

    UPDATE Tablename 
       SET Datecolumn = GETDATE() 
      FROM 
     WHERE ID = (SELECT i.id FROM INSERTED i)

  END
```

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is just a little off:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trUpdate 
ON dbo.Tablename 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE Tablename 
    SET Datecolumn = GETDATE() 
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT id FROM inserted);
END
GO
```

Now what you should do is change the column to `NOT NULL` and a default of `GETDATE()`. Then you only have to fire this trigger on update.

```
-- first clean up any remaining NULL values:
UPDATE dbo.Tablename 
  SET DateColumn = '19000101'
  WHERE DateColumn IS NULL;

-- now add the default constraint:
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tablename ADD CONSTRAINT
  DF_Tablename_DateColumn DEFAULT(GETDATE()) FOR DateColumn;

-- now add the NOT NULL constraint:
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tablename ALTER COLUMN DateColumn
  DATETIME NOT NULL;

-- now you can update the trigger so that it only fires on update:
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trUpdate 
ON dbo.Tablename 
FOR UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE Tablename 
    SET Datecolumn = GETDATE() 
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT id FROM inserted);
END
GO
```

Comment: Sorry more of a typo,Thanks a million, worked like abracadabra!,ur good!

Comment: The 1st trigger worked for me,it logged date/time stamp for any insert or update i made as I changed the Table Xture (dateColumn NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()) before Implementing ur solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
 UPDATE Tablename 
       SET Datecolumn = GETDATE() 
  WHERE ID = (SELECT i.id FROM INSERTED i)
```

TO

```
IF NOT UPDATE(Datecolumn)
UPDATE Tablename 
       SET Datecolumn = GETDATE() 
  WHERE ID IN (SELECT i.id FROM INSERTED i)
```

since the inserted table might conain more than one enty. Otherwise it should work fine.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: sorry, missed the dangling from, edited the code